# Doubt regarding quadratic sieve

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Is calculating $a^2 \equiv p-5 \pmod{p} $ same as calculating $a^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{p} $ ?My code (using quadratic residue method) returns same answers corresponding to both the equations for any odd prime $p$.

For example :-

For $a^2 \equiv 99986 \pmod{99991} $, my $a$ comes out to be 10104.

For $a^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{99991} $, my $a$ comes out to be 10104.

Comment: Can't be. You have a mistake. -5 and 5 mod 99991 are different elements of the modular groups Z/99991Z. Since $$10104^2$$ is indeed $$5 (mod 99991)$$, the first equation is wrong.

Comment: @mousomer : Thanks for pointing out my mistake. It's actually p-5 where p is equal to 99991

Comment: But $$p-5(mod\ p) = -5(mod\ p)$$

Comment: Thanks @mousomer . But does there exist any solution to equation $a^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{1000000007}$ ?

Comment: https://exploringnumbertheory.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/solving-quadratic-congruences/

Comment: I see where you're trying to go... you mixed the solution to the equation with the equation  itself. Yes, if $$x^2=5\ (mod\ p)$$ and you've found that 10104 solves the equation, then $$p-10104$$ solves the same equation. But none of them solve the equation $$x^2=-5\ (mod\ p)=p-5\ (mod\ p)$$